# Start bluetooth from termux command line

Tags: android, command-line, termux

Is it possible to enable/start bluetooth from command-line within the termux terminal on a non-rooted phone/tablet running Android 8?

Use case: Enable bluetooth and connect to my keyboard when I run termux.

I guess I could use tasker to achieve something similar but last time I used tasker, it has a significant impact on battery life.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. Someone needs to do some android programming and make termux able to use the android bluetooth API.

See https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/235 for an open feature request.

Comment: I made this https://github.com/StevenSalazarM/termux-app-bluetooth and https://github.com/StevenSalazarM/termux-api-bluetooth. Termux-api apk is no needed since I included it inside termux-app-bluetooth. Currently only termux-bluetooth-scaninfo is working. I hope someone can update the answer.